# Smartgit Ubuntu won't fit the screen

Tags: smartgit

we installed the latest version SmartGit 6.5 on Ubuntu 12 and it won't fit the screen. It's bigger and some controls are hiding. Version 2 didn't have such a problem. Is it some Java thing? How to fix that?

Comment: How large your screen is?

Comment: Standard 1280x1024 resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed SmartGit 6.5 on Ubuntu 12.04 in VMWare and it fits fine in 1280x1024 for the default theme "Ambiance". You may try to remove some toolbar buttons or change the order of the tool windows and then reopen the window.

[image: SmartGit 6.5.1 on Ubuntu 12.04]